# How to use count() with text file in python

Tags: python, file, text, count

I'm a really confused beginner and would like to know what I should be doing to make this work. My IDE is not giving me an error, just no output.

I want to count how many times a word is found in a book's text file, in this case "the" is the word:

```
with open('heidi.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    content.count('the')
```

Comment: ```count``` is for lists. You should do ```content = file.readlines()``` and then split each string inside the list

Comment: Maybe call `print(content.count("the"))`? Also, this will pick up instances of `"the"` in other strings, like `"there"`.

Comment: @Sujay `count()` also works for strings as it is iterable

Answer (score 2):

The example I was learning from was running it in the console so I didn't know I needed to use print(). Thank you @hilberts_drinking_problem.

```
with open('heidi.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    print(content.count('the '))
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` doesn't print anything. So give a variable, like this -

```
with open('heidi.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    a = content.count('the') 
    print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works, although I prefer to not use the extra variable 'a' and do print(content.count('the')) since content itself is a variable